# Can we store value of @yield in a variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a simple question can we store the value that will be yielded in a variable.

for instance an example

```
$var = @yield('title')
```

If no, then is there any way to get the value of this `yield`

Comment: what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Well... if it can or not? that is the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can retrieve the value of an `yield` which is defined by a `section` using something like the following, for example:

```
// Assumed you've the following in your view: @section('title', 'Some Title')

$title = app()->view->getSections()['title']; // Some Title
```

Basically, the `app()->view->getSections()` will return you an associative array of all the sections so, to get a specific `section`, all you need to get an specific index from the array. From the view, you can access the `app` using the global `$app` variable, i.e: `$app->view` or `$app['view']`.

Comment: Most Welcome :-)